# What are the differences between "could" and "can" when stating a possibility?

Tags: american-english, can-could

For demanding payments there are two ways to say :

1. You could transfer to this account
2. You can transfer to this account

Both make a grammatical sentence. Are there subtle differences between them I should be aware of?

Comment: Hi ishita, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! This particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) StackExchange instead.  In addition, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is less strict.

Comment: A 'demand' sounds like 'You must transfer to ...' or just 'Transfer to ...' fits best! If you want to make a polite but firm request, 'You can ...' is fine. 'You could ...' is certainly grammatical here, and even more polite, but (unless you are suggesting various alternative modes of payment) sounds a little weak.

Comment: I've changed the question so it doesn't ask "Which is correct?" when they both are.